# What does "unrestricted treatment effect heterogeneity" mean?

Tags: econometrics, nonexpert

[Borusyak, 2021](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/b1e55330-f605-363c-b07f-3ab67325e929/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B47d22c8f-e7ba-3ead-9833-eeae8a94d5f0%7D) has a sentence

> We show that this estimator takes a particularly transparent form
> **under unrestricted treatment effect heterogeneity**, while our
> construction also yields efficiency when some restrictions on
> treatment effects are imposed.

I am wondering what does **under unrestricted treatment effect heterogeneity** mean? I translate it to that "**when the treatment effect heterogeneity is not restricted**", and it also means that this situation works in both cases "**treatment effect heterogeneity**" and "**treatment effect homogeneity**". Is it a correct thought?

I did [ask this in the English Learner](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/297815/what-does-unrestricted-treatment-effect-heterogeneity-mean/297819#297819) but they said this content is beyond the English language question.

The answer from English learner's expert is

> However, I am more inclined to interpret it as "the transparency of
> our estimator when there are no restrictions is greater than the
> transparency of other people's estimator when there are no
> restrictions" and "the efficiency of our construction when there are
> restrictions is greater than the efficiency of other people's
> construction when there are restrictions."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"unrestricted treatment effect heterogeneity" means the effect of treatment can differ for each individual, and there are no assumptions or limitations on how the effect differs.

Diff-in-diff models using twoway fixed effects with heterogeneous treatment effects and heterogeneous treatment times are known to be biased. [Sun and Abraham 2020](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030440762030378X) is a major reference.

This idea has very recently become a hot topic in econometrics. While I haven't read the paper you cite, it appears to be pushing this idea forward even more.

Comment: @Micheal , exactly this idea, it is mainly about the heterogeneous treatment onset. Just the language confuses me a little bit. Thanks a heap

Comment: I think "Diff-in-diff models using twoway fixed effects with heterogeneous treatment effects and heterogeneous treatment times are known to be biased" should be " "Diff-in-diff models using twoway fixed effects with **homogeneous** treatment effects and heterogeneous treatment times are known to be biased". Is it correct?

Comment: I don't think so. I think if treatment effects are homogeneous, then things are fine. The Sun and Abraham results (theorem 3) would imply this. There is of course a chance I am unaware of something.

Comment: Ah yeah, it is what I mean, if the treatment effect is homogeneous (very rare case), things are fine. I may mistranslate your words.